# How to determine Property name causing a System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How can I determine which property is triggering this ArgumentNullException?

Somehow a property in my model is not being submitted on an Ajax POST. I can't see the problem using Fiddler - all of the form values look valid. I don't think it's what I am submitting, it's what I am NOT submitting.

```
ERROR 2021-02-28 15:24:53,942 [62   ] ations.Web.Controllers.ReportsController - Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: value
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: value
   at System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationContext.set_DisplayName(String value)
   at System.Web.Mvc.DataAnnotationsModelValidator.Validate(Object container)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ModelValidator.CompositeModelValidator.<Validate>d__2.MoveNext()
   at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.OnModelUpdated(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindComplexElementalModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Object model)
   at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindComplexModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.GetPropertyValue(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor, IModelBinder propertyBinder)
   at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindProperty(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor)
   at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindProperties(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindComplexElementalModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Object model)
   at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindComplexModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValue(ControllerContext controllerContext, ParameterDescriptor parameterDescriptor)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValues(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.<BeginInvokeAction>b__0(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState)
```

Comment: You can debug and see it right?

Comment: No. I can see the controller's constructor being hit, but not the action.

Comment: Post a copy of your C# model and json data being sent across by javascript.

Comment: @TejSoft I appreciate your offer to help. In this case there are over 1000 fields posted back to the controller. I've scoured through the HTTP POST using Fiddler and Chrome DevTools. The error is being thrown in the ModelBinder? I'd like to know how to debug in the standard ModelBinder class.